# Geoserver sending BigDecimal data as String in vector tiles

Tags: postgis, geoserver, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js

Setup details:
Geoserver: 2.12.1
DataStore: PostgreSQL 10.1 with PostGIS 2.4.2
mapbox-gl: 0.42.0

I am using mapbox-gl to render vector tiles from geoserver using TMS. I am styling the tiles using data-driven styling as explained [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/data-driven-circle-colors/). The styling works amazingly for most of the part, but there are few datasets which are not being styled properly.
The problem occurs in case of **interval** based styling on an attribute which is not of *Integer* type in the postgreSQL tables.

The following are snapshots of the table:

postgres# \d+ layer_data

```
  Column  |   Type  
----------+--------  
  lat     |   numeric
```

On the Geoserver portal (Edit Layer --> 'Data' tab), the layer attribute looks like:
[image]

The feature data received on the mapbox-gl in JSON form is as follows:

```
{
  "__mlocate__created_by": 1,
  "__mlocate__created_date": "2016-05-02",
  "__mlocate__id": 343620,
  "__mlocate__layer_id": 410,
  .
  .
  "altitude": "0",
  "country": "India",
  "date_issue": "No",
  "id": "27283",
  "lat": "27.038510519999999",
  "lng": "88.459210400000003",
  .
  .
  .
}
```

The URL being hit by the browser to get tiles is:
http://localhost:6792/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/biodiv:lyr_410_butterflyspeciesdistribution@EPSG:900913@pbf/2/3/2.pbf

The style file does data-driven style as below:

```
'circle-color': {
        property: 'lat',
        type: 'interval',
        stops: [
          [6, '#eee4e5'],
          [12, '#cdaaea'],
          [24, '#bd82f8'],
          [37, '#9c55f1'],
          [49, '#8129fa'],
        ]
      }
```

The styling doesn't work and all circles are just drawn in black color. I guess this is because the value of 'lat' field is being interpreted as *String* (notice that this value is enclosed in quotes in JSON data as opposed to some other values, which are *Integer* type in the database) and hence the styling is not working.
But since this is defined as numeric data type in postgres, is it the geoserver that is sending it as a wrong data type in tiles information or is it mapbox-gl who is mis-interpreting the information send by Geoserver?

Comment: if the circles are drawn in the correct place then the error is probably with your style not the coordinates

Comment: @IanTurton The circles are in correct place because the geometry filed is in correct format. The 'lat' value here is an additional attribute and not used for marking circles.

Comment: @PriyanshuAgarwal I saw your post in the Geoserver mail group, did you ever find a solution. I have the same problem with big decimals being sent as strings.

Comment: @mappingdom The feedback I had received from the geoserver guys was that the vector tiles was still evolving and not every data format is supported yet. Unfortunately, Big Decimal was one of them. I did not think of a workaround as this was a low priority task for me. In case you figure something out, please put it here as an answer.

Comment: No I followed these (https://www.service-architecture.com/articles/database/mapping_sql_and_java_data_types.html) and recast the numeric type in the source db as a work round